# Error using GET() and Data Table in R (Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE)

Tags: r, api

I am trying to use the GET() function to run through my data.table
which contains columns of Postal Code (Canada) but I keep running into the following error

```
 Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

My code looks like the following

```
returnMLA <- function(postalCode){
    urlMLA <- paste("https://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/",postalCode, sep="")
    res<-GET(urlMLA)
    data<-fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
    return(data)
}

people <- data.table(a=c(1,2),b=c("V8S1N5","V8V3E9")) 
people[,MLA:=returnMLA(b)]
```

I know this is because I am sending multiple URLs to the GET() function. Is there a way to make this work with data.table?

I can resolve the error with

```
people[,MLA:=returnMLA(b[1])]
```

but it will only return same response

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` -

```
library(data.table)

people[, MLA := lapply(b, returnMLA)]
people

#   a      b       MLA
#1: 1 V8S1N5 <list[7]>
#2: 2 V8V3E9 <list[7]>
```